# JavaScript date time conversion not returning the value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to convert timestamp (in millis) into date and show it into a table cell. Below is the code I wrote for conversion.

```
var start = match.startAt;
    console.log(start);
    var startTime = new Date(start);
    var t = startTime.toLocaleDateString
```

and I am displaying it as

```
<td>{t}</td>
```

In console, it is just showing "ƒ toLocaleDateString() { [native code] }"
I couldn't figured out why it is not displaying anything. Can someone help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be     `var t = startTime.toLocaleDateString()` not     `var t = startTime.toLocaleDateString` because `toLocaleDateString` is a `function`

Comment: a small mistake can ruin a lot... thanks @Mohammad Ali Rony

Answer (score 2):

Should invoke the function.

```js
var start = match.startAt;
console.log(start);
var startTime = new Date(start);
var t = startTime.toLocaleDateString // wrong
// var t = startTime.toLocaleDateString(); // correct
```